# Initialize an array after it's created in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `Building` class that represents an array of `Room` objects. Each room has some properties which are irrelevant for now.

I am getting the rooms from user input like this:

1. First-line is the number of rooms.
2. The next n lines give information about the rooms in this format: `"[room index] [room properties...]"`. The index of each room ranges from 0 to n -1.

Example input:

```
3
0 [room 0 properties: a, b]
2 [room 2 properties: x, y]
1 [room 1 properties: u, v]
```

which should create the object:

```
Building: rooms: [Room(a, b), Room(u, v), Room(x, y)]
```

I can't guarantee that the rooms will be given in order, but I can promise that all rooms will be given as input.
If I was in Java, I could easily write code like this:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Room[] rooms = new Room[in.nextInt()];
for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
    int roomIndex = in.nextInt();
    // Get room properties from rest of line input
    rooms[roomIndex] = new Room(...);
}
```

However, in kotlin, there is a little problem with this approach: I have to initialize the `rooms` array when I create it. I can't create an uninitialized array, like in Java, and then initialize it in a loop. The `Array` constructor in kotlin takes a size and a lambda parameter to initialize the array **in the order of the indices**. As I said, I can't promise the input will be given in the order of indices. I can only promise that all rooms will be given and initialized.

I can create an array of nullable rooms (`Array<Room?>`), but I don't like this idea because all rooms will be given, so null checks and assertions will be useless when using the array later.

Is there a way to create an uninitialized array in kotlin, and tell the compiler not to freak out about this because I promise the array will be fully initialized after the loop runs?

I didn't find a way to cast an `Array<Room?>` to `Array<Room>` without creating a copy of the array, which seems wasteful for me. I also don't think I can use something like `Array<lateinit Room>` as I can do with regular non-collection properties. The only solution I came up with is to initialize the array with a dummy `Room` object and then actually initialize it in the loop:

```kt
val dummy = Room(...) // dummy object with useless properties
val rooms = Array(size) { dummy }

// Real initialization in a loop
repeat(rooms.size) {
    val properties = readline()!!.split(' ')
    val roomIndex = properties[0].toInt()
    // Parse rest of properties
    rooms[roomIndex] = Room(...)
}
```

What is the best way to create such an array? I don't think I should use `Array<Room?>` because I can promise every element of the array will be non-null after the loop, and I don't like the idea of a dummy object, but it might be the best bet? Do you have another suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a List, not an Array. Lists are the go-to collection in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't find a way to cast an Array<Room?> to Array without creating a copy of the array

Casting doesn't create a copy of the array (or any other object one cast). It just creates new variable with different type, but the same reference (see [proof](https://pl.kotl.in/mGoTJ4b71)).

Also, you may create an auxilary function, wrapping nullable array creation and casting:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified T> buildArray(size: Int, builderAction: Array<T?>.() -> Unit): Array<T> =
    arrayOfNulls<T>(size).also(builderAction) as Array<T>
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val rooms = buildArray<Room>(size) {
    val properties = readLine()!!.split(' ')
    val roomIndex = properties[0].toInt()
    set(roomIndex, Room(...))
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I am feeling dumb. I didn't know you can cast an `Array<T?>` to `Array<T>` using the `as` operator. I was thinking about the `filterNotNull` method, which does create a copy of the array